# Why won't this execute if block command work in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm playing in the new snapshot, 18w01a.

I'm trying to detect if a hopper has a specific renamed item in it using this command:

```
/execute if block "x" "y" "z" minecraft:hopper{Items:[{id:"minecraft:paper",tag:{display:{Name:"12345"}}}]} run say hi
```

I have a piece of paper renamed 12345 in the hopper and the command fails when I try to run it. If I remove the tag/display/Name argument, the command runs fine, but that's no help to me. I'm sure I don't have the syntax wrong, so what gives? Is this a bug? If it's not a bug, I won't report it on the bug tracker, but right now I'm a little iffy.

Comment: What do you mean by the command fails? What error is given, or does it simply give no response?

Comment: Try an easier command/a part of the command first. Many things changed in 1.13, so it could be the `execute` part, the NBT structure of the hopper, the item part, the name part, ...

Comment: I think you need to specify a slot somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1.13, the syntax for display names changed to text components. In my case, we'd have to write it as:

```
/execute if block "x" "y" "z" minecraft:hopper{Items:[{id:"minecraft:paper",tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text:\":\"12345\"}"}}}]} run say hi
```